# NodeJS Database Update Query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

When I use this code, it only updates one value of the database that is first value. It does not work on a loop; only one row is affected. I want to update all the rows. How can I select a column value from table and update it to other column values in a loop?

asyncloop  approach: -

```
   function readData () {
      return new Promise (function(resolve,rejection){
        conn.connect().then(function () {
          var request = new sql.Request(conn);
          request.query('Select * FROM demo Order by id  ;', function (err, data) {
            if (err) { console.log(err) }
            else {
              try {
               resolve(data)
                conn.close();
              }
              catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
              }
          });
        });
      });
    }

   function writedata() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, rejection) {
    let count = 0
    asyncLoop(temp, function (item, next){
      asyncLoop(id,function(newitem,newnext){
      conn.close();
      conn.connect().then(function () {
        var request = new sql.Request(conn);
        console.log(item);
        console.log(newitem);
        request.input("language", sql.VarChar, item)
        request.input("id", sql.SmallInt, newitem)
        request.query('update demo set ru = @language where  id = @id ;', function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            try {
              count++
              conn.close();
              if (count == 4) {
                resolve(data)
              }
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            next();
            newnext();
          }
        });
      });
    });
    });
  });
}



readData().then(function (data) {
  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    temp.push(data['recordset'][i]['EN']);
    id.push(data['recordset'][i]['ID']);
  }
  writedata().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Updated The code with asyncloop but some loop problem there

Comment: First, use another file or global object to set connection. And print sql query and run it into phpmyadmin or something to check. Also print @id before query so we can check the details.

Comment: @Sagar i Updated The Code With Second approach as title It Also Updates only a single row

Comment: @Sagar Updated The Code Please Check

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, notify me for any errors. Also, modifiy count value according to need:

```
    function writedata() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, rejection) {
            let count = 0
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                conn.close();
                conn.connect().then(function () {
                    var request = new sql.Request(conn);
                    console.log(temp[i]);
                    console.log(id[i]);

                    request.input("language", sql.VarChar, temp[i])
                    request.input("id", sql.SmallInt, id[i])
                    request.query('update demo set ru = @language where  id = @id ;', function (err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        } else {
                            try {
                                count++
                                conn.close();
                                if(count == 5)
                                   resolve()

                            } catch (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: It Didint Worked It Prints Undefined undefined in console

Comment: you forgot to set parameters to function.  function writedata(), it should be  function writedata(temp,id)

Comment: @DHIRAJKATEKAR I have Taken array As global variable then Why Parameter ?

Comment: @DHIRAJKATEKAR Added In Question please Check

Comment: @Sagar Code not Working Giving undefined in console

Comment: update your calling code, remove declaration of temp and id from calling code, also your are passing parameters to the write function which are not necessary as you have declared them globally

Comment: @DHIRAJKATEKAR By Mistake Updated Wrong code Please Check Now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172559/discussion-between-dhiraj-katekar-and-amey).

Answer (score 1):

please try `Asyncloop` instead of `for` loop below is the syntax for the same.

```
asyncLoop(ARRAY, function(item, next) {

    [Function/Operation block]
        next();
    }
});

}, function(error) {
    [Error Handling Block]
});
```

Comment: Please Check above Code Some  minor Looping problem see if it can be corrected

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, i hope it helps

```
let updateData= []



let updateDataRows = async (tmp, identifier) => {
    console.log('updating row',tmp,identifier);
    conn.close();
    await conn.connect();
    let request = new sql.request(conn);
    console.log(tmp);
    console.log(identifier);
    request.input("language", sql.varchar, tmp)
    request.input("id", sql.smallint, identifier)
    let data = await request.query('update demo set ru = @language where  id = @id ;')
    conn.close();
    return data;
}
let writedata = async () => {
    let resData = await Promise.all(updateData.map(async (d) => {
        return await updateDataRows(d.temp, d.id)
    }));
    return resData;
}

readData().then(function (data) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        updateData.push({
            temp: data['recordset'][i]['EN'],
            id: data['recordset'][i]['ID']
        })
    }
    writedata.then(data => {

    }, err => {

    })
});
```

Comment: It just Goes on a loop and print values in console and node hangs